# Why is the data is not plotting on top of global map in R?

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, rgdal, rworldmap

I am trying to plot annual and decadal difference in sea surface temperature data from the world ocean atlas (https://www.nodc.noaa.gov/cgi-bin/OC5/woa18/woa18.pl) in 1 degree with a netcdf file.

I have managed to create a global map but I am unable to overlay the annual data to it. Is there something missing from my code? Is it possible to add latitude and longitude along the x and y axis? And can I just subtract the 2005 - 2017 decadal data with 1955 - 64 decadal data or do I need to do something to the data? Thank you!

```
remove(list=ls())
library(rgdal)                                                                                                      
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(palr) 
library(rworldmap)
library(reshape2)
library(raadtools)
library(raadfiles)
library(sp)
library(spbabel)
library(dplyr)


datafile <- "/Users/Desktop/woa18_decav_t00_01.nc"
path_split <- stringr::str_split(basename(datafile), ".")
img_basename <- basename(datafile)
img_startdate_string <- substr(img_basename, 2,8)
image_startdate <- as.Date(strptime(img_startdate_string, "%Y%j"))


pprj <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0, 0, 0"
target_extent = c(-180, 180, -90, 90)


g4 <- rgeos::gBuffer(SpatialPoints(cbind(0, 0), proj4string = CRS(pprj)), 
                 width = spDists(rbind(c(-180, -90), c(-180, -90)), longlat = TRUE, segments   = T) * 1000, 
                quadsegs = 180)
data("countriesLow", package = "rworldmap")
sptable(countriesLow) <- subset(sptable(countriesLow), y_ > -84)
w <- crop(rgeos::gBuffer(spTransform(countriesLow, CRS(pprj)), width = 0), g4)



pal <- palr::sstPal(palette = TRUE)
target <- raster(g4)
res(target) <- c(25000, 25000)
sst <- projectRaster(raster(datafile), target)
sst <- mask(sst, g4)



#png("/Users/Desktop/plot1.png", width = 300, height = 300, units = "mm", res = 400)
par(mar=c(6,6,4,4))
plot(w, col="grey",  breaks = pal$breaks, asp = 1, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5,  xlim =     c(xmin(w), xmax(w)), ylim = c(ymin(w), ymax(w)))
mtext(text =  image_startdate, side = 3, line = 0) #need this to state the decadal difference
image(chl, col = pal$cols[-1], breaks = pal$breaks, add = TRUE)
plot(g4, add=TRUE)
plot(w, col="grey", add=TRUE, breaks = pal$breaks, asp = 1, cex.axis=1.5, cex.lab=1.5,  xlim = c(xmin(w), xmax(w)), ylim = c(ymin(w), ymax(w)))
#dev.off()
```

Comment: I've had issues with `raster` not recognizing the spatial reference information stored in netcdf files. What does `crs(raster(datafile))` return?

Comment: I get this error with crs(raster(datafile)). > crs(raster(datafile))
CRS arguments:
 +proj=longlat +lon_0=0 +a=6378137 +rf=298.257232666016 
Warning messages:
1: In .varName(nc, varname, warn = warn) : varname used is: n_an
If that is not correct, you can set it to one of: n_an, n_mn, n_dd, n_sd, n_se, n_oa, n_gp
2: In .rasterObjectFromCDF(x, type = objecttype, band = band, ...) :
  "level" set to 1 (there are 102 levels)
3: In .getCRSfromGridMap4(atts) : cannot process these parts of the CRS:
epsg_code=EPSG:4326 I don't actually understand what it means.

Answer (score 2):

This code is working for me

```
nc_file <- "https://data.nodc.noaa.gov/thredds/dodsC/ncei/woa/temperature/decav/1.00/woa18_decav_t01_01.nc"

library( ncdf4 )
library( raster )
library(maptools)

#read nc-file
ncData <- nc_open( nc_file )
#get longitude, latitude and temperature
lon  <- ncvar_get( ncData, "lon" )
lat  <- ncvar_get( ncData, "lat" )
temp <- ncvar_get( ncData, "t_an")
#check
dim( temp )
#[1] 360 180  57    lon, lat, depth
#depth[1] = surface, so we take that slice
surface_slice <- temp[, , 1]
#close connections
nc_close( ncData )

#create raster
r <- raster( t( surface_slice ), 
             xmn = min(lon), 
             xmx = max(lon), 
             ymn = min(lat), 
             ymx = max(lat), 
             crs = CRS( "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0" ) )
r <- flip(r, direction='y')
plot(r)
#add countries
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you! is it possible to change the axis cut-offs? i.e. 0, 45, 90 on the y-axis and I can do the same for the x-axis? using this code, I could subtract one decade from the other and plot the difference, so thank you!

Comment: like this: `plot(r, xaxt = "n", yaxt = "n" );
axis(1, at = seq(-180, 180, by = 45), las = 2);
axis(2, at = seq(-90, 90, by = 45), las = 1)`

Comment: That's roughly what I did in the past as well. A word of warning, though: at least in my case the values of lon and lat stored in the netcdf file were for the *center* of the raster cells, so by using the minima/maxima of these as the bounding box you'll be off by half a cell – which may or may not matter depenting on what you're planning to do with the data.

Comment: Thank you! I don't quire understand what you mean @Where'smytowel. Do you mean that the data will be off by half a grid? how could I correct it?

Comment: If all you want to do is plot a global map: forget about it. But if precision is a concern: Have a look at the coordinates (`head(lat)` and `head(lon)`): they're equally-spaced out at 1°-intervals, but they're all at x.5 degrees because they represent the center of the cell. Unless I'm very mistaken, xmn, xmx etc. in the raster() command refer to the left edge of the leftmost cell, right edge of the rightmost cell etc. You can correct for that by adding/substracting half a degree from the maxima/minima: `xmn = min(lon)-0.5`, `xmx = max(lon)+0.5`, `ymn = min(lat)-0.5` and `ymx = max(lat)+0.5`.

Comment: You're welcome! Easiest way to verify that everything is matching up: export the raster as geotiff, create a SpatialPoints* or similar object from the lat and lon coordinates and export as shapefile or similar. Load both into your GIS of choice, put the points on top of the raster and zoom in until you can see the individual raster cells. Check the edges and the center of the global map: points need to be located the center of the raster cells.